# Why do my capacitors keep inflating?

Tags: capacitor

I have a 7 year old Vizio soundbar that, when it works, is amazing. In the past 8 months, it has broken twice. The first time, I found some troubleshooting advice on a Reddit page that suggested that it’s a broken capacitor.

I opened up the soundbar and sure enough, the exact capacitor was swollen like a balloon. I removed it and replaced it with a new capacitor. It was all good for 5-6 months and then went dead again. I opened it back up and there was a new capacitor that was swollen up. I replaced that and it turned on for a couple hours then went dead.

Here is my first question:

Why do my capacitors keeps breaking? It just swells up. While I’m perfectly ok with and considering just pulling all the capacitors and replacing them with new ones, I want to identify what’s causing them to break like this. Does anyone have any ideas on what could cause the capacitors to break out of nowhere and what I could fix to save the new capacitors?

Here is my second question:

I’ve attached some pictures below. This time, I don’t seem to identify any swollen capacitors. I’d appreciate it if someone can attempt to identify the broken component from these pictures.

Please let me know if this question doesn’t belong here. I couldn’t find a better page for this.

[image: board 1 pic 1]
[image: board 1 pic 2]
[image: board 2 pic 1]
[image: board 2 pic 2]
[image: board 2 pic 3]

Just a disclaimer, I’m an absolute novice at electrical stuff. But I do know how to do a clean solder. So if a simple component change is all it is, I might be able to do that. I just want to save this soundbar if it’s possible.

Comment: Is it the same capacitor position that dies or different?

Comment: The two times were two different spots. This time, after replacing the second one, I can’t even spot a swollen capacitor.

Comment: Usually you replace all the caps of a type (or even all types) once one leaks since the others may go bad soon after. In this case it sounds like that happened. No idea bout why your device failed the last time, may need to do some reverse engineering to find the bad component.

Comment: If you put in a wrong type of capacitor, it might not work for long. For example switch mode power supply output capacitors need to handle large ripple currents so they might be low ESR types. If you replace such with a standard capacitor that can't handle the current, it will degrade faster, runs hotter and leads to more ripple voltage so it may cause other parts of the system fail to operate.

Comment: I guess your question is whether there is a common failure on such boards which *causes* capacitors to fail, like a failing voltage regulator or such. Since *heat* is a killer one thing to check is that fans (if any) are working and all ventilation openings are free (no dust, nothing lying on them, not covered in any way), and the whole assembly is not lying on a plush carpet etc.

Comment: @user1850479 I suppose you are implying that the least durable parts, which are the capacitors, simply have reached their end of life. Could be. Capacitors are a bit of black magic items and not entirely trivial to get right -- anybody remember the [capacitor plague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague)?? I think it even affected pacemakers, sending patients back into surgery. It is probably always possible for a manufacturer to catch a sub-par batch.

Answer (score 7):

There's plenty of space on your board. Use capacitors rated for a higher voltage and higher temperature than the ones installed. Check that diameter and length still fit in. Chances are the original ones are sized too tight at their operation limits.

Buy them from a well known distributor, as those parts are often counterfeited.

Comment: As someone who’s very uneducated and inexperienced in this, could you point me to reliable websites to get quality components from? Also, how do I look for fatter capacitors with the same specs as mine? Can I just replace all my capacitors with bigger ones even if it isn’t the same spec?

Comment: To start with, mouser.com and digikey.com are reliable distributors with good parts search filtering, even sparkfun and adafruit are trustworthy; but avoid 'marketplace' sites like amazon marketplace, alibaba, ebay, because anyone can sell anything there -- there's no accountability or traceability. If the product page doesn't clearly link to a datasheet and an RoHS materials declaration, it's not a professional-quality distributor.

Comment: Also the caps must be rated with low ESR which causes less self heating and outgassing of electrolyte.

Comment: It’s just reliable Japanese suppliers but cannot be std E-cap , must be low ESR, and RoHS is irrelevant

Comment: I’ll get a bunch of higher voltage and higher temperature caps with the same μF as the current ones. The answer below mentioned Nichicon brand as good. I’ve seen that being available widely so I’ll get that brand. I appreciate the comments!

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 low ESR might be counterproductive if the ESR of the caps are used to stabilize a transfer function. LDOs often rely on the zero provided by the ESR and the track resistances in series with the capacitance. Replacing such a cap with a low ESR one, will push the zero at higher frequencies, and de-stabilize the regulation loop, causing ringing, or even oscillation in extreme cases.

Comment: @HorrorVacui. Yes I know that's true for low current CMOS LDO's as it suppresses the feedback.  What makes you think that's relevant for this design?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 It was a general comment from my side. We know very little about this design. Such could be the case for the smaller caps near analog ICs. For the big caps at the switching regulator it has to be good to replace them with a low ESR one, but at other places, the role of the cap should be investigated first. Replacing the cap with same type, slightly higher rated components should be the safe way.

Comment: Raising the voltage on a std e-cap only reduces ESR  only slightly with rising voltage, whereas low ESR is are 1% of std ESR * C<10us vs std ESR*C>100us when comparing same brand. People usually choose the cheapest parts that meet your criteria will end up with similar short life span. This is always about high ripple current SMPS. So my opinion your answer is insufficient (-1)

Answer (score 4):

Since you state you're a novice at electronics...
Aluminum electrolytic capacitors are polarized. Be sure you install the replacement capacitors correctly with regard to polarity.

More likely, the capacitors are probably used in switching power supply circuits. You need to replace the capacitors with types rated for switching supplies, not general purpose varieties. These will be low ESR (equivalent series resistance) types. The capacitors that were originally used in your sound bar are crappo Chinese capacitors that will last no more than 5 years before failing. Replace them with good quality Japanese capacitors (United Chemi-Con, Nichicon, Panasonic, ...). Digikey and Mouser have lots to choose from. As a starter, you can look for United Chemi-Con UPW, KZE, and KZN series capacitors.

Comment: The second set of capacitors I bought were nichicon! Go figure, I guess. I’m thinking of getting “higher voltage”, “higher temperature” but “same μF” Nichicon caps. I did get the polarity right. I’ll watch for that. Thank you.

Comment: If it would have been a polarity problem, than it would have blown up instantly after the card is powered on. I believe only the behemoth caps on the single-layer boards are for the switching supplies.

Comment: @CrazyCucumber Please note that capacitors of reputable brands like Nichicon are counterfeited at a shocking scale. How sure are you that your caps are genuine? If you bought them off some online mega-marketplace, chances are high that they are fakes. Stick to reputable specialized part suppliers if you want any kind of reliability.

Comment: @TooTea yeah the Nichicon I purchased were from Amazon. This time I won’t be making that mistake, I’m going with mouser now

Comment: I've seen a wrong polarity AL electrolytic last a few years before failing in an Ethernet switch. We were all amazed that the device worked for as long as it did.